# Filtering by number of rows a primary key has

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which sometime returns rows that are not needed.

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT 
    ca.item_id, ca.FIELD_ID, ca.attr_val, ca.upd_dtt, ca.upd_usr
FROM 
    contract_attr ca
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM contract_attr ca_326
            WHERE ca.item_id = ca_326.item_id
              AND ca_326.field_id = 326
              AND ca_326.ATTR_VAL = 'Y')

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    ca.item_id, 9999, mf.[ITEM_NAME], '', ''
FROM 
    mfr mf
JOIN 
    contract_attr ca ON ca.attr_val = mf.[ITEM_PK]
ORDER BY 
    ca.item_id
```

[image]

item_id's 10-13 on the image only have 1 row.

I want to filter these rows from the query. Looking it up I'm supposed to add a having:

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT 
    ca.item_id, ca.FIELD_ID, ca.attr_val, ca.upd_dtt, ca.upd_usr
FROM 
    contract_attr ca
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM contract_attr ca_326
            WHERE ca.item_id = ca_326.item_id
              AND ca_326.field_id = 326
              AND ca_326.ATTR_VAL = 'Y')

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    ca.item_id, 9999, mf.[ITEM_NAME], '', ''
FROM 
    mfr mf
JOIN 
    contract_attr ca ON ca.attr_val = mf.[ITEM_PK]
HAVING 
    COUNT(ca.item_id) > 1
ORDER BY 
    ca.item_id
```

But I am getting this error and don't understand why:

> Column 'contract_attr.ITEM_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: since you have a bunch of other fields you want returned you probably want to use the having with a sub-query, or if the grouping is sufficient add it to a group by clause.

Comment: @scsimon When you say subquery do you mean wrapping the whole thing?

Comment: something like `...JOIN contract_attr ca ON ca.attr_val = mf.[ITEM_PK] INNER JOIN(SELECT item_id FROM contract_attr group by item_id having count(item_id) > 1) x on x.item_id = ca.item_id` in your second part of your union. Basically add that one inner join

Comment: @scsimon Perfect, this solved it. Put an answer if you would like.

Comment: No worries @davidTunnell glad to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are wanting to return multiple columns which wouldn't be able to be done with the grouping required by having, you can use having in a sub query.

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT 
    ca.item_id
    ,ca.FIELD_ID
    ,ca.attr_val
    ,ca.upd_dtt
    ,ca.upd_usr
FROM contract_attr ca
            WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM contract_attr ca_326
        WHERE ca.item_id = ca_326.item_id
            AND ca_326.field_id = 326
            AND ca_326.ATTR_VAL = 'Y'
        )
UNION ALL
SELECT ca.item_id
    ,9999
    ,mf.[ITEM_NAME]
    ,''
    ,''
FROM mfr mf
JOIN contract_attr ca ON ca.attr_val = mf.[ITEM_PK]
INNER JOIN(SELECT item_id FROM contract_attr group by item_id having count(item_id) > 1) x on x.item_id = ca.item_id
ORDER BY ca.item_id
```

Comment: Nice job deciphering that from the question and image +1

Comment: thanks @SqlZim it's just habit for me with `HAVING` really. I usually want to use it in a large statement. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `group by`:

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT ca.item_id
        ,ca.FIELD_ID
        ,ca.attr_val
        ,ca.upd_dtt
        ,ca.upd_usr
    FROM contract_attr ca
                WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM contract_attr ca_326
            WHERE ca.item_id = ca_326.item_id
                AND ca_326.field_id = 326
                AND ca_326.ATTR_VAL = 'Y'
            )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ca.item_id
        ,9999
        ,mf.[ITEM_NAME]
        ,''
        ,''
    FROM mfr mf
    JOIN contract_attr ca ON ca.attr_val = mf.[ITEM_PK]
    group by ca.item_id, mf.[ITEM_NAME]
    HAVING count(ca.item_id) > 1
    ORDER BY ca.item_id
```

Comment: This appears to filter to everything. Nothing returns for the 2nd JOIN.